# How to justify text in ReportLab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to create a pdf document with reportlab, one of the texts is long, and reportlab writes it in a single line, it does not generate the break, I inserted the text in part, but I need to justify it, so that it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your text in `reportlab.platypus.Paragraph` to get auto wrapping